# How to get data of a particular user from firestore database and show it in recyclerview in android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have an Android app in which users can upload book. On home screen book of all the users is shown. In profile section, there is a button named byBooks which can be used to get all the book uploaded by the current user. Please help me get all the books uploaded by the current signed in user and show it in the recycler view.

This is my book dao

```
class BookDao {

    private val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val bookCollection = db.collection("books")

    fun addBook(book: Book?){
        if (book!= null) {
            bookCollection.document(book.bookName).set(book)
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I am populating the recycler view of home fragment which shows all the books.

```
val bookDao = BookDao()
        val bookCollection = bookDao.bookCollection
        val query = bookCollection.orderBy("createdAt", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
        val recyclerViewOptions = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Book>().setQuery(query, Book::class.java).build()

        mAdapter = HomeAdapter(recyclerViewOptions)
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also add the code that you're using to get the books that correspond to a specific user.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added the database screenshot. I don't know how to get the books of a specific user. I have added the code that I am using to get all the books.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer

```
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid
        val reference  = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("books").whereEqualTo("userId", uid)
        val query: Query = reference.orderBy("createdAt")
        val recyclerViewOptions = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Book>().setQuery(query, Book::class.java).build()

        mAdapter = HomeAdapter(recyclerViewOptions)
```